# How I can get the current focused element of desktop application

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto

I want to automate my test case for my desktop application(windows application) where I need to get/fetch the currently focused element. Can someone please help me or guide in this regard?

I tried with GetFocus method of pywinauto which just returned the details of Active Window but I need focussed element info

Comment: Do you mean the child element with keyboard focus?

Comment: I want to get the current focussed element, for e.g the user open a personal information form and the foccused element is the textbox of Name field. Now I want to get to the currently focused item which is Name field in this case. I have used get_focus but that did not work for me because getfocus() gives me the window, I need particular item/element.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not implemented, but the workaround is possible. For "win32" backend:

```
import win32gui
from pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper import HwndWrapper
keyboard_focused = HwndWrapper(win32gui.GetFocus())
```

For "uia" backend (may not work for WPF app):

```
import win32gui
from pywinauto.controls.uiawrapper import UIAWrapper
keyboard_focused = UIAWrapper(win32gui.GetFocus())
```

I've filed [issue #760](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/760) to implement it later.

Comment: win32gui.GetForegroundWindow() gave me better success than GetFocus(), which always returned 0. Also, to install win32gui you should install the pywin32 package (trying to pip install win32gui gives errors).

Comment: in uiwrapper.py, if element.control_type in UiaMeta.control_type_to_cls:, AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'control_type'

Comment: and 'Handle 0 is not a vaild window handle' using HwndWrapper

Comment: @pf12345678910 please post these errors as separate question with full traceback. Or please create a new issue in GitHub repository. Thanks!

Comment: @pf12345678910 such error messages are typically come from incorrect usage. Your code sample is really needed to help you writing correct code. pywinauto has pretty high learning curve, but it is powerful and reliable enough. So it is your choice to search for help or search for blame reasons.